# how to remove Duplicate from list array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var cars = [
    { year: 2007, model: "Ford F-150" },
    { year: 2011, model: "Toyota Camry" },
    { year: 2007, model: "Ford F-150" },
    { year: 2007, model: "Ford F-150" },
    { year: 2005, model: "Dodge RAM" }
    { year: 2005, model: "Dodge RAM" };
];
```

How Remove duplicate from this array list

Comment: You have a missing comma and an extra semi colon.

Comment: Smells like a homework.

Comment: @Jeff This is not a duplicate, OP has array of objects so those solutions would not work in his case.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to filter duplicates base on [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) condition, this works for simple items. In your case you can't use it because two similar objects in array are not identical so `indexOf` will not help.

For this situation it is convenient to make use of [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var cars = [
    { year: 2007, model: "Ford F-150" },
    { year: 2011, model: "Toyota Camry" },
    { year: 2007, model: "Ford F-150" },
    { year: 2007, model: "Ford F-150" },
    { year: 2005, model: "Dodge RAM" },
    { year: 2005, model: "Dodge RAM" }
]; 

cars = cars.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    var inArray = prev.some(function(car) {
        return car.model === curr.model && car.year === curr.year;
    });
    if (!inArray) {
        prev.push(curr);
    }
    return prev;
}, []);

alert(JSON.stringify( cars, null, 4) )
```